# How do I start clojurescript repl with lein mies?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, read-eval-print-loop, leiningen

I'm trying to learn clojurescript.

In my terminal (on Mac) I typed

```
lein new mies js-practice
cd ~/js-practice
scripts/repl
```

Then I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node": error=2, No such file or directory,
```

I'm confused, because I'm following a tutorial line by line and I don't understand what I did wrong. Am I missing some simple command? Is there something I don't have downloaded?? I'm a total beginner so I really can use any pointers.

Thank you!!

Comment: I've never heard of `lein mies`.  Have you looked at Shadow CLJS?  https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs

Comment: For reference, here is [mies](https://github.com/swannodette/mies). I also had never heard of this project!

Comment: mies is severely outdated by now and really shouldn't be used for anything new. you are better off following the official [quick start](https://clojurescript.org/guides/quick-start) or using one of the common tools (eg. lein-figwheel, fighweel-main or shadow-cljs)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem! I didn't have Node.js installed. I did

```
brew install node
```

And now scripts/repl works.

I feel kinda silly but as a beginner these basic things drive me crazy! :)

I will also look into shadow cljs at some point since that seems to be more commonly used. Thanks!